# log in button does not work . i nned to log in in this project for solving other problem

Tags: java, reactjs

i have a problem :can not login on the front end even if i created user on my sql and associated to role admin. front end is in react . could you please guide me if you know what is the problem derive from. i add here all codes on the spring boot java back-end part .

i created a user with all attributes which are created on spring boot : usaer name, tel, email and is_active. I guess i didnt created user correctly. For attribute is_active i inserted true on my sql.i need to log in for add some entry and solve other problems.

thanks again,

public class User implements java.io.Serializable {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NonNull
@Size(max = 20)
private String username;


@NotBlank
@NonNull
@Size(max = 50)
@Email
private String email;


@NonNull
@Size(max = 12)
private String telefono;

@JsonIgnore
@NotBlank
@NonNull
@Size(max = 120)
private String password;

private Boolean isActive = false;

@JsonIgnore
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

public User(@NonNull String username, @NonNull String email, @NonNull String telefono) {
    this.username = username;
    this.email = email;
    this.telefono = telefono;
    this.password="";
}

public Set<Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}

public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}
```

}

Comment: please post your full codes, like security configuration and password encryption. or share a link to the project in your GitHub.

Comment: now i have another error :Request failed with status code 401
 my codes in password part are :  password: yup
    .string()
    .min(5, "Password troppo corta")
    .matches(passwordRules, { message: "Password troppo debole" })
    .required("Campo obbligatorio"),
  confirmPassword: yup
    .string()
    .oneOf([yup.ref("password"), null], "Le password devono corrispondere")
    .required("Campo obbligatorio"),